# Android in app billing: If in app purchase is controlled by primary device account then how to prevent passing accounts

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Lets say there is an app that offers in app purchases, If user A came and bought `item X` from the app then I think from what I understand that his/her primary device account will remember what user A bought (assume the primary email is : `userA@gmail.com`).

So that now `userA@gmail.com` knows that `item X` is a purchased item.

If user A gave user B his/her primary account (`userA@gmail.com` with the password) then user B will add this email as his primary account, and user B will simply access `item X` and this is the same for any user that might happen to know user A.

**My question:**

If user purchases are remembered by their primary account, then how to prevent users to pass their accounts to each other and access things for free?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, as you can give your password to another person. In this case, the user remains the same, only the device changes. **In-App billing associates a product ([consumable/non-consumable](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api#consumetypes)) to a userID.** The question here is not on the in-app billing side, but in how the game actually handles the item consumption.

**Let's put things in another perspective:** you buy something on device A, with account X. Then you try to login on device B, with account X. Your stuff will remain there (sometimes games have a "refresh purchases button", that in fact just call the in-app billing services to retrieve the products/items associated with that userID, so that the game can refresh the items in-game), but if you login with an account Y, that never purchased anything, even on device A, the in-app billing will retrieve nothing (because you never purchased anything in on account Y), so you will see nothing purchased in your app/game.

You can purchase stuff, and pass your account to other people, but they will not be able to "move" or "trade" items from your account into theirs.

**EDIT:** However you can try and add the [`getPurchases()`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference#getPurchases) method, so that it can retrieve the non-consumed items of that userID, after the login.

Comment: Thanks. But the question is how to not allow the passing of accounts?

Comment: I want every user to buy the items.

Comment: It will simply not allow it. Users will not be able to trade items, only if your app/game allows it in-app/in-game. From the service perspective, you are only selling products, that will be redeemed in-app/in-game. If a user logs their accounts on someone elses phone, they will only have their products. The question here isn't about the service per say, but with your app/game allowing the same user being logged in on multiple devices. If you can only be logged with one device, the in-app billing service will not allow to "move" or "copy" products between accounts.

Comment: But google play allows you to open your account from multiple devices, so this is my problem. What should I do?

Comment: Get Purchases method after login will ensure that you will get products for that particular userID after the login, and you need to clear the data from the previous login, so that you only have the products for that userID

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the clear data, clear what??

Comment: In your app/game you will have an object to store the info that comes from the service right? Like products or items. You need to clear that before calling the getPurchases(). This way, you will clear the object from the previous user's info, and update it with the response products from the new method call, after logging in.

Comment: Okay I understand what you said, but I want a way that doesn't allow users to be able to access each others data. I want to avoid users giving accounts to each other. Example: if user A paid for an item and gave his primary email to user B then I end up with user A and user B opening the same primary email and both of them will query the same item that was only paid by user A........conclusion user B never paid....how to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: But they will still play/use the same account, meaning if one of them "consumes" the item, it will be consumed for the other one aswell. I'm trying to answer your question without any knowledge of your app/game capabilities. Maybe if you can share a bit more of the app/game goal, I can help in further detail.

Comment: This happens with many games/apps, where people buy something, and then share with other people. It's called piracy :)

Comment: What would you do in this case?

Comment: One possible workaround in this case would be in app/game authentication, meaning you could control the account access, and only allowing 1 logged user. Even if they bought using google play, they would not be able to have the same inapp/game account logged in multiple devices.

Comment: So you mean I have users authenticate and save the purchases they make using a database?

Comment: But then they will still be able to give the authentication details to each other right?

Comment: Yes they will, but only you could make access rules so that the account could be logged in one single device. If another user logged in using the same account you could retrieve a "User already signed in another device" error, for example.

Comment: Yes I understand it seems a solution.......But in your opinion do you think it is efficient? Can we make it a bit harder?

Comment: This is a bit of an hard topic, because many applications nowadays have to deal with this kind of troubles. Take Netflix for example: nothing can guarantee that i have an active subscription, and that i can lend my account to someone else, for them to get the "profit" of free using of my account, while I'm paying for the service. That's why they have a defined number of devices that can be connected to the account, simultaneously... This is one way to try and ensure that only one user can use it, but its difficult to guarantee, because I can lend my account while I'm not using it...

Comment: If you had too much security, you will have less flexible user experience, meaning users will comply that they can't lend their accounts to their brothers/sisters while they are not using it. See where I'm getting at? :)

Comment: Ah I get it, but why netflix doesnt do the case where 1 user logs in the other goes out.

Comment: They could do that, but that could result in complaints. Imagine I could steal your account and when I logged in, it would logged you out. I could change passwords inside your account and make sure you could never access it. Of course that would result in me having access to your email account aswell... It's "cleaner" to block account access from the outside, meaning a user couldn't access the same account if that account was logged in another device, than logging out any existing users when another one tried to login... but its doable.

Comment: Ah thanks for your time and effort. Maybe one shouldn't be very secure as you said.

Comment: There is no such thing as a perfectly, secure and flawless system... yet :D

Comment: Yes I agree. :)